# Is there a way to pass a list into model.objects.values() in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I want to only display specific columns from my model,
I know this way works:

```
Transactionlog.objects.values('column1','column2','column3')
```

But I have a list I need to populate into, I'm using django filters so my code looks like this:

```
filtered_transactions = transactionFilter(
                request.GET,
                queryset=Transactionlog.objects.values('column1','column2'))
```

My problem is that I have a dynamic list being populated via a seperate model, and i need to pass this list into values(), but it doesn't take list, from what i can tell anyway.

my solution so far ( horrible for large datasets...and small):

```
if len(column_list) == 1:
    filtered_transactions = transactionFilter(
            request.GET,
            queryset=Transactionlog.objects.values(column_list[0]))
if len(column_list) == 2:
    filtered_transactions = transactionFilter(
            request.GET,
            queryset=Transactionlog.objects.values(column_list[0],column_list[1]))
...
```

Please tell me there is another way of doing this, becuase this is driving me up the wall!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an asterisk (`*`) to unpack an iterable into inividual parameters:

```
filtered_transactions = transactionFilter(
        request.GET,
        queryset=Transactionlog.objects.values(*column_list)
)
```

It is however *odd* to use `.values(…)` in the first place. Normally one fetches the objects, and then *renders* certain columns. By using `.values(…)`, one erodes the logical layer a model provides. So properties, etc. defined on the model are no longer accessible.

Comment: Thankyou so much, such a simple solution! yes, I agree with what you say: I'm rendering the data to a table with the columns being defined by a userpreference table, so the data rendered will be different per user, that being said, could you recomend a better way to have the table dynamically populate as per a user preference? I had tried doing this via js( dynamically hiding columns that werent' needed by the user, but i found this way would clutter